# Multiple Panes with MouseListener on top of each other

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have an issue with mouse listeners added to 2 different panels one on top of the other. Both of them make use of the `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()` methods.

The expected outcome of the test code bellow is:

- When I hover on the frame a **red** rectangle should be made visible
- When I hover on the **red** rectangle in the frame it should turn **blue**.
- When my mouse exits the now **blue** rectangle (but still inside the frame) it should turn **red**
- When my mouse exits the frame entirely the now **red** rectangle should not be visible

If I try to move my mouse over the colored rectangle it keeps flashing from visible to not visible. The system print shows what I mean, it keeps activating Mouse Entered and Mouse Exited every time I move or click with my mouse. Is there anyway to prevent the `mouseExited()` method from being called every time I move or click my mouse?

Here is the test code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Sandbox extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.add(new Sandbox());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public Sandbox() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        final JPanel panelA = new JPanel();
        panelA.setBackground(Color.red);
        panelA.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(155, 155));
        panelA.setVisible(false);

        this.add(panelA, BorderLayout.WEST);

        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

                System.out.println(" -  MOUSE ENTERED ");
                panelA.setVisible(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

                System.out.println(" -  MOUSE EXITED ");
                panelA.setVisible(false);
            }

        });

        panelA.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

                System.out.println(" #  MOUSE ENTERED ");
                panelA.setBackground(Color.blue);

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                panelA.setBackground(Color.red);
                System.out.println(" #  MOUSE EXITED ");
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that behavior, because you have 2 listeners. When you try to change color to `blue` it changed, but from first listener executed `panelA.setVisible(false);` and you don't see that.

You can fix that in next way: change code of `mouseExited()` method in first listener:

```
   @Override
   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        if(!panelA.contains(e.getPoint())){
             panelA.setVisible(false);
        }
        System.out.println(" -  MOUSE EXITED ");
   }
```

EDIT: one more fix for exiting from frame when mouse on `panelA` : change `mouseExited` for second listener :

```
 @Override
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    panelA.setBackground(Color.red);
        if (!Sandbox.this.contains(e.getPoint())) {
            panelA.setVisible(false);
        }

        System.out.println(" #  MOUSE EXITED ");
  }
```

Comment: safe could be with add/remove (delegate events from_to only one MouseListener can be added on runtime) MouseListener from JFrame to JPanel and vice versa, a few code lines more over